# Samsung Galaxy Nexus keeps rebooting in Cyanogenmod 11 as well as in CWM recovery. How to backup data, or repair the ROM?

Tags: cyanogenmod, backup, samsung-galaxy-nexus, reboot

I have a Samsung Galaxy Nexus. I have installed CM11 a while ago, but for about a week it keeps rebooting too often; it stays on for about 10-15 seconds, and then reboots.

I haven't installed anything suspicious in it. I just noticed that I can't update it to the latest version; I don't know why.

So I tried few things to backup my phone and wipe it with fastboot; tried to update to newest version of CM11 from CWM, but without any luck. It even keeps rebooting if I am in CWM.

Can you guys point me in the right direction? Maybe I am missing something. I keep searching for solutions, but cannot find any idea about how I can backup it, or maybe repair the ROM. I just need the Contacts and Photos from the phone.

`adb logcat` http://pastebin.com/S2RjfWmA

Comment: The things you can try are: run `adb logcat` and get some info if possible. Remove SIM and/or SD-card and try again. Boot into recovery, is there still an old version left you could flash?

Comment: @ott-- but how would OP try to use adb if the device keeps rebooting.The connection will break just every time, even CWM recovery reboots.

Comment: I haven't any old version left on device, but this would make device not boot at all, because CM doesn't have the possibility to downgrade.

Comment: @Denees Do you have any fastboot type ROM with firmware files in it. I suggest flashing everything except the userdata (Internal SD card). Or, may be try flashing a new recovery first (like TWRP) and see if it reboots in this recovery as well.

Comment: I'll try to install TWRP with Nexus Toolkit at home, now I'm on Linux. But what you mean "any fastboot ROM"?

Comment: @Firelord He said 10-15 seconds before reboot. Whole universes can be born within that time.

Comment: @Denees By fastboot type ROM, I meant a ROM having files that are supposed to be flashed using `fastboot flash` command and not via recovery. E.g see this [link](https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/mirrors-for-official-cyanogen-roms-ota-updates.141825/) for differences between fastboot ROMs and flashable zips.

Comment: @ott-- Possibly, can't argue. :)

Comment: @Denees Please use @ to notify. I won't be notified since there are three of us here now.

Comment: Ok @Firelord, thx. So guys I managed to get `logcat` from device, here it is http://pastebin.com/S2RjfWmA I'll update my post as well.